# Xirsys v3 demo setup

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, xirsys

I am attempting to get the demos project setup for xirsys v3 on windows 10.

I have updated the credentials for the node server with my credentials from the portal but I receive a timeout error when entering the room.

It is a websocket connection timoeout issue.
I can see in the console window of the server the requests for the tokens on entering the room but nothing happens after this.

The documentation links in the portal do not work as they are pointing to port:9000 which is either down or is an error.

I have followed the startup guide on github https://github.com/xirsys/xirsys-examples-v3 but to no avail. any help would be appreciated.

David

Answer (score 3):

I just ran through the Xirsys v3 on windows 10 and the HTTP traffic, running over port 3080, was not being redirected to the HTTPS server, running on port 3443. In order to run our xirsys v3 examples they must be securely hosted on HTTPS server.

The websocket connection issue could have definitely been caused by the example app not being ran over HTTPS since the websocket used is secure(wss), and can only run on a HTTPS server.

We have just pushed an update of the [Xirsys v3](https://github.com/xirsys/xirsys-examples-v3) to github, so please try again.

If you run into the same or any other issues please feel contact us directly at support@xirsys.com

Also I had no issues navigating to any of the Xirsys docs hosted on port 9000, can you please provide us a specific URL?

Noe

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It looks like you're a representative of Xirsys. We welcome product support, but be sure to have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) for some best practices on how to provide support here. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Thanks bwDraco, for the guidance! We'll be sure to address Xirsys specific questions and issue accordingly next time.

Comment: Hi @NoeVega! I also have a question related to Xirsys, about an example that uses only PHP. I created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422849/xirsys-webrtc-cant-find-sdp-object?noredirect=1#comment93721011_53422849 Could you assist me?

Answer (score 1):

Websocket connections require a ping message to be sent periodically from the client.  This is because, should the client disconnect unexpectedly, the server can clean up the connection, as Websockets don't natively handle this automatically.  Your websocket should be sending the string "ping" no less frequently than 20 seconds apart.